# Get the top users per day

Tags: discussion, support, api

Is it possible to get the top users per day or per period (month,year,week)?

I know it's possible to get the top answerers per tag, but what I want is the top user per day.

1. API to get the top user per period?
2. Also is it possible to get the questions answered by the user for the given period? I am interested in getting the tags of the questions answered for the given period..any API for that??

UPDATE:
Can the above problem be solved using  http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/min-max in any way???

Comment: This feature already exists for week, month, quarter, year, and all-time. Just not per day.

Comment: but that is per tag not overall.                                  http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/top-answerers-in-tag and this is not what i want..i want to get the data of top users for a given month

Comment: It exists for overall. Per-tag actually only has month, and all-time.

Comment: [Per week.](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=week) [Per month.](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=month) [Per year.](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=quarter) [Per quarter.](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=year) [All time.](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)

Comment: What is the api call for that??

Comment: You didn't specify in your question that you wanted the API for it.

Comment: i tagged the question as API...will update that as part of my question

Comment: Ah... totally overlooked that. My fault.

Comment: It does exist per day.  Sunday.

Comment: can you provide a link to the api ?